# Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `exists?' for File:Class when compile flutter app

Tags: ruby, flutter, cocoapods

Today when I compile my flutter(`v2.5.0`) app, shows error:

```
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳

    [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `exists?' for File:Class.

     #  from /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/flutter-netease-music/ios/Podfile:34
     #  -------------------------------------------
     #  
     >    flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
     #  end
     #  -------------------------------------------
```

this is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS"] = "x86_64"
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
    end
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

I have read this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/109385#issuecomment-1212616254 told that the exists was removed in newer version of ruby. How to change my podfile to avoid this problem? Any one facing the similiar issue?

Comment: how did you solve it then?

Comment: how did you solve it then?

Comment: It's long time ago and I have already forget how to fixed this issue.